# Ubuntu detecting two external monitors as only one?

Tags: multiple-monitors, display

I have two external monitors connected to my laptop via docking station.

With my laptop lid closed, displays is showing only two monitors

1) Built in Display and
2) Dell Inc 22"

second external monitor is not detected as an external monitor.

Please see the picture below:

[image]

I like to have extended monitor..Could somebody please help me on this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you first try ***without*** the docking station to make sure this is even possible with your hardware (1 primary display + 2 external - I suspect maybe some docking stations only support 1 external display?)?

Does it work in Windows (if you can test that)? If it works ***without*** the docking station or in Windows, then you can easier narrow down the problem (conclude that the problem is not software-related)? It's always a good approach to systematically try things out, to narrow down the problem (explain what you've tried and why).

Comment: Having the same issue. It does work on window and it does work if I'm connecting the monitors through two different USB-C ports, but not when using the docking station, in which case it recognizes the two monitors as a single one and mirrors them..